# Kubernetes set-up on ubuntu on Google compute

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

Can any one help me understanding this error I am getting while trying to set-up kubernetes. I am trying to follow this [url](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/gce.html) and run the command

```
$ curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The component manager is disabled for this installation
```

### I am running the command on google compute Ubuntu machine. Appreciate any help

Adding the complete error ( Ubunut 15.4), after full blown google sdk installation
.............
Unpacking kubernetes release v1.0.3
Creating a kubernetes on gce...
Starting cluster using provider: gce
... calling verify-prereqs
You cannot perform this action because the component manager has been
disabled for this installation.  If you would like get the latest
version of the Google Cloud SDK, please see our main download page at:

https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The component manager is disabled for this installation
You cannot perform this action because the component manager has been
disabled for this installation.  If you would like get the latest
version of the Google Cloud SDK, please see our main download page at:

https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The component manager is disabled for this installation
You cannot perform this action because the component manager has been
disabled for this installation.  If you would like get the latest
version of the Google Cloud SDK, please see our main download page at:

https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The component manager is disabled for this installation
... calling kube-up

Comment: **Got this working**.. Since I was running the google VM.. I had to install in separate directory and work from there.. Looks like my full blown installation didn't works as expected. IronYuppie http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=google-containers helped.. Closing this thread.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem here. per "install in separate directory", can you post the steps and commands? I installed a new version of google cloud sdk, but it still gives me this error when I ran kube-up.sh

Answer (score 32):

The problem is that some ubuntu (and others) distro come with the google cloud SDK installed through the local package manager, but it doesn't contain everything. kubectl for example is missing as seen with this command:

```
gcloud components list
```

when you try to add the needed component for Kubernetes with:

```
gcloud components install kubectl
```

you end up with this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The component manager is disabled for this installation

It is a known issue on the Google Cloud SDK issue tracker : [Issue 336: kubectl not installed by google-cloud-sdk debian package, and not installable](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=336)

Unfortunately, it provides a poor experience for first timer testing kubernetes as it's hard to find a quick AND CLEAN step by step solution.

Here is one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove google-cloud-sdk
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
exec -l $SHELL
gcloud init
gcloud components list
gcloud components install kubectl
gcloud components list
```

this last command should show kubectl installed and everything up to date.

Comment: Saved a lot of time!!

Comment: Same issue with google cloud functions documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Get yourself a full-blown Cloud SDK installation:

`$ curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash -`

And follow instructions. Don't forget to remove old binaries to prevent clashes (script will warn you towards the end of the install). Then, proceed with Kubernetes setup again.

Comment: I get the same error after the  installation and installation replaced the old binaries, atleast asked for it... After installation it gave following message Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXXXX/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 20, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.gcloud import gcloud
  File "/home/XXXXX/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 184, in <module>
    _cli = CreateCLI()
..... .......

Answer (score 0):

The latest Google SDK package manager installs:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#apt-get

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#yum

now support installing kubectl "directly" from the repo:

`sudo apt install kubectl
sudo yum install kubectl`